# Page navigation from View Model

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I want to realize a page navigation from ViewModel.
As you can see in the code there is a frame in the mainwindow that have to be filled with pages.

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition MaxWidth = "175" ></ColumnDefinition>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid Grid.Column="1">
        <Frame Background = "Gray" NavigationUIVisibility= "Hidden" Name = "mainFrame" Margin= "0,0,5,0" >
        </Frame>
    </Grid>
</Grid >
```

In the MainWindowViewModel I implemented the method of the command which has to be executed by clicking on the butteon "Go to the Next page". This method is called "ExecuteOpenTestResultsRecoveryPage"

```
private void ExecuteOpenTestResultsRecoveryPage(object parameter)
{
    RecoveryPage recoveryPage = new RecoveryPage();
    MainWindow mainWindow = new MainWindow();
    mainWindow.mainFrame.NavigationService.Navigate(recoveryPage);
}
```

By clicking on the button "Go to the next page" the method is executed but nothing happens in the frame and I don't understand why. Please can you help me to realize it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are editing `new MainWindow()` 's `mainFrame`'s content. Not your current one.

```
(Application.Current.MainWindow as MainWindow).mainFrame.Content = recoveryPage;
```

try this.

Comment: Thank you all for your suggestions. I was able to solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't recommend that you open a new MainWindow when you want a new page to display. It's better to send a message to the View to show the particular other view. That way you can achieve separation of concerns.

Answer (score 0):

You're instantiating another instance of mainwindow.
This is just in memory.
You then set it's frame's content to your usercontrol.
But you never show this new mainwindow.

You could get a reference to the existing mainwindow something like:
 var theMainWindow = Application.Current.MainWindow as MainWindow.
Then set the frame's content on that.
This would usually be considered bad practice though.

I recommend you google viewmodel first.
The way this'd work is you define a viewmodel for each thing you want to navigate to.
Associate a UserControl ( not a page ) with each using datatype=. That goes in a resource dictionary you merge in app.xaml.
Then use a contentcontrol ( not a frame ) in your mainwindow to host these.
Expose a public property CurrentViewModel from mainwindow viewmodel and bind the content of your contentcontrol to that.Change out that property to a different viewmodel and it will then be templated into the associated usercontrol.

This is a standard pattern you should be able to find samples for fairly easy.